# JSON Stringify Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to stringify an array to achieve this JSON:

```
{"fields":{"TITLE":"title text",
"NAME":"name text",
"EMAIL":[{"VALUE":"email@domain.com","VALUE_TYPE":"WORK"}],
"PHONE":[{"VALUE":"555-111-222", "VALUE_TYPE":"WORK"}],
"ASSIGNED_BY_ID":"10",
"SOURCE_ID":"WEB",
"STATUS_ID":"ASSIGNED",
"COMMENTS":"comments text"}
}
```

Here is my code:

```
var Lead = {};
Lead.fields = {};
Lead.fields.TITLE = $("#name").val();
Lead.fields.NAME = $("#name").val();
Lead.fields.EMAIL = {};
Lead.fields.EMAIL.VALUE = $("#eml").val();
Lead.fields.EMAIL.VALUE_TYPE = "WORK";
Lead.fields.PHONE = {};
Lead.fields.PHONE.VALUE = $("#phone").val();
Lead.fields.PHONE.VALUE_TYPE = "WORK";
Lead.fields.ASSIGNED_BY_ID = "4";
Lead.fields.SOURCE_ID = "WEB";
Lead.fields.STATUS_ID =  "ASSIGNED";
Lead.fields.COMMENTS = "Finest Meetings Contact Form:" +$("#comment").val();
var DataParsed = JSON.stringify(Lead);
```

This achieves everything apart from wrapping the email and phone elements in the square brackets and thus subsequently my post up to the REST API fails.  Obviously I could manually construct the JSON string with everything in the right place manually, but is there an easier way to instantiate the EMAIL and PHONE arrays to put them in automatically?
Thanks

Comment: Make default JSON and push your data accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simplify this code a lot.

Just declare your structure like this, instead of accessing each individual property like you did:

```
var Lead = {
  fields: {
    TITLE: $("#name").val()
    NAME: $("#name").val(),
    EMAIL: [{ VALUE: $("#eml").val(), VALUE_TYPE: "WORK" }],
    PHONE: [{ VALUE: $("#phone").val(), VALUE_TYPE: "WORK" }],
    ASSIGNED_BY_ID: "4",
    SOURCE_ID: "WEB",
    STATUS_ID: "ASSIGNED",
    COMMENTS: "Finest Meetings Contact Form:" +$("#comment").val()
  }
};

var DataParsed = JSON.stringify(Lead);
```

As you can see, this looks a *lot* like your desired output already.

Answer (score 0):

As you said said it yourself, it's an array, so this should work:

```
Lead.fields.EMAIL = [{}];
Lead.fields.EMAIL[0].VALUE = $("#eml").val();
Lead.fields.EMAIL[0].VALUE_TYPE = "WORK";
Lead.fields.PHONE = [{}];
Lead.fields.PHONE[0].VALUE = $("#phone").val();
Lead.fields.PHONE[0].VALUE_TYPE = "WORK";
```